# Google map api key is invalid for generated domain?

Tags: google-maps

Yesterday I was for the fist time try google maps API, and I was generate API key for one of my public domains. Maybe I made a mistake, because I was test that key on my localhost and that was work fine, but when I try to publish that on my website I got the javascript alert which said that my API key is not valid for that domain, but I was generate that key for that domain. What is the trick?

Comment: Each domain must have its own key. Are you sure you are using the appropriate keys for each of your domains (i.e. domain + localhost)?

Comment: I'm use same key for localhost and domain. On localhost it works, but on domain thats not the case. I got that key from google, for domain not for localhost, so mu questin is why it's not working on domain if it's generate for domain, silly :)))

Comment: Keep in mind that Google says that keys always work for localhost, but are tied to the domain the key was registered for. Sounds like this key wasn't generated for that domain.

Answer (score 1):

The key is always working for localhost, for testing purposes. But on other domains, the domain has to match the domain, you have registered the key with. So, did you control, if it really matches? No typo in the domain you registered yur key with? Or do you use a subdomain? Another problem could be, that Google wants your application (which uses the map) to be accessible from the web, without asking for passwords or similar hurdles.